# The Box Jesse Made in Breaking Bad

Tags: breaking-bad

In *Breaking Bad*, Jesse attends an addiction circle for drug addicts where they share their experiences and things and in the episode “Kafkaesque“ Jesse talked about a box he made.

At first, he says he gave it to his mom, but a bit later he confesses and admits that he sold it for an ounce a weed. Way later in the last episode of the series “Felina” it shows a flashback of Jesse making a box.

I don’t hear many people talk about it, but is the box from the flashback the same one he made and sold for an ounce of weed?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: We could be seeing Jesse imagining what it would be like to make a brand new box!

Answer (score 3):

If you recall, Jesse described that wooden box as something he was able to do really well and that brought him a lot of pride.  It appears that Jesse is tied to that memory via his ability to cook meth exceptionally well, and it's something he took pride in.  It almost acts as bookends to Jesse's character, to show two extremes of abilities he has; one as a productive member of society and one as the lowest and most destructive members of society.